# How resize image in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

My code resize Image, but it only can reduce size.

```
 For Each oFile In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(parm_strTargetPath)
                If oFile.ToString.ToLower.Contains(".png") Or oFile.ToString.ToLower.Contains(".jpg") Or oFile.ToString.ToLower.Contains(".jpeg") Then
                    Dim strFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(oFile)
                    Try
                        Dim original As Image = Image.FromFile(oFile)
                        Dim resized As Image = ResizeImage(original, New Size(h, w))
                        Dim memStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                        resized.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg)

                        Dim file As New FileStream(result & "/" & strFileName , FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
                        memStream.WriteTo(file)
                        file.Close()
                        memStream.Close()
                    Catch ex As Exception

                    End Try

                End If

            Next
```

My image size: `1028x 172`, i want resize to `500 x 500`
But result is a image size : `500x84`
How Resize image from `1028x 172`  to `500 x 500` ?
Thanks all.

Comment: You'll get an ugly image if you don't keep the ratio.. You could draw it on a white/black background.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 Dim resized As Image = ResizeImage(original, New Size(h, w), False)
```

instead of

```
 Dim resized As Image = ResizeImage(original, New Size(h, w))
```

Comment: Any chance of a bit more explanation, like what leaving out the False actually does?